# IDataErrorInfo Validation for Telerik RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Updated to the latest Telerik WPF Controls and they have changed how validation in cell of a RadGridView work. After updating the version validation holds the focus in a cell which is not valid. Any suggestions how I can turn off this feature?

Comment: Have you considered asking Telerik? Their support is pretty good. You could well find nobody here has experienced your issue.

Comment: I already wrote in theirs forum but I don't have an answer yet

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `ActionOnLostFocus="None"`.